# Haskell - filter typeclass

Tags: haskell, filter, typeclass

Is there a typeclass which abstracts the `filter` function?

I am thinking about something like

```
class Filterable t where
  filter :: (a -> Bool) -> t a -> t a
```

If this isn't the case, is there an explicit reason for it?

Comment: You're approaching it backwards. Can you think of an explicit reason why there *should* be such a class? Think about what constructors (aside from `[]`) for which you might define an instance.

Comment: looking [here](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=filter), I think it would make sense to have a `Filterable` instance for `[]`, `Set`, `Seq`, `Map k`, `IntMap`, and all newtypes built above them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the witherable package [provides `Filterable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable-0.3/docs/Data-Witherable.html#t:Filterable), with a handful of instances for common types.

Comment: thanks a lot! still, it doesn't work for `Set`, since `Set` is not a functor

Answer (score 3):

There is `mfilter` method in `Control.Monad` ([link](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:mfilter))

```
mfilter :: MonadPlus m => (a -> Bool) -> m a -> m a
```

Comment: thanks, but does `t` really need to be a Monad to support a filter operation? It appears to me that a filter operation should be independent from Monad

Comment: You can create your own class (but you have to chose other name for method) and implement it for `MonadPlus`. It will work for existing containers like `[]` and `Maybe` since they already in `MonadPlus`.

Comment: @marcosh not just Monad, but MonadPlus. there's also `foldMap (\x -> [x | p x])` or an equivalent for your `t` type -- either as is, with Foldable (plus an "injector", like `pure`... ;) ), or with MonadComprehensions (getting `(Monoid (m b), Foldable t, MonadPlus m) => (b -> Bool) -> t b -> m b`).

Comment: thanks. I know I could do this. I wanted to know if there was something ready in full generality (for example `mfilter` won't work on `Set`) and if there was a practical (or theoretical) reason for its absence

Comment: This is actually very interesting to me, I'm hoping more answers/comments come up.. It's apparent that you (probably) can't `filter` over an arbitrary `Functor` or `Foldable` - I can't see how you could realistically filter any type of tree, for example (what do you do for example with a tree whose root value fails the predicate but where everything on each branch passes it?). But I'm as surprised as you that you need a full `MonadPlus` for this. It's also not at all clear to me what laws the `filter` operation should follow in general in order to be worthy of the name.

Comment: @RobinZigmond The Haskell Wiki provides some analysis here. In short, Foldable is about tearing down structure while Traversable is about preserving structure as-is, so neither let you write `filter`. You need a structure-building operation like `pure` and some notion of 'empty' (`mzero`), which is why `mfilter` works. But you don't need the rest of the structure from `Applicative` or `Monad` and could use `mempty` instead of `mzero`: `filter p = foldMap (\a -> if p a then pure a else mempty)`. https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldable_and_Traversable#Some_trickier_functions:_concatMap_and_filter

Comment: @RobinZigmond It is quite curious, indeed. `Filterable`, `Alternative` and `Monad` are only loosely connected, and yet they all come together so that `MonadPlus` gives out a rigorously sensible implementation of `filter`. For further exploration of this theme, see also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60732274/2751851).

Comment: @RobinZigmond One can develop a `Filterable` typeclass with its own laws, quite independently of `Monad` or `Alternative` or any other typeclass. One can even have contravariant `Filterable` type constructors. The most concise definition for `Filterable` functors is the method `deflate :: f (Maybe a) -> f a` which must satisfy suitable laws of identity and composition.