# Is every Alternative Monad Filterable?

Tags: haskell, filter, monads, category-theory, alternative-functor

The category of sets is both cartesian monoidal and cocartesian monoidal. The types of the canonical isomorphisms witnessing these two monoidal structures are listed below:

```
type x + y = Either x y
type x × y = (x, y)

data Iso a b = Iso { fwd :: a -> b, bwd :: b -> a }

eassoc :: Iso ((x + y) + z) (x + (y + z))
elunit :: Iso (Void + x) x
erunit :: Iso (x + Void) x

tassoc :: Iso ((x × y) × z) (x × (y × z))
tlunit :: Iso (() × x) x
trunit :: Iso (x × ()) x
```

---

For the purposes of this question I define `Alternative` to be a lax monoidal functor from Hask under the `Either` tensor to Hask under the `(,)` tensor (and no more):

```
class Functor f => Alt f
  where
  union :: f a × f b -> f (a + b)

class Alt f => Alternative f
  where
  nil :: () -> f Void
```

The laws are just those for a lax monoidal functor.

Associativity:

```
fwd tassoc >>> bimap id union >>> union
=
bimap union id >>> union >>> fmap (fwd eassoc)
```

Left unit:

```
fwd tlunit
=
bimap nil id >>> union >>> fmap (fwd elunit)
```

Right unit:

```
fwd trunit
=
bimap id nil >>> union >>> fmap (fwd erunit)
```

Here is how to recover the more familiar operations for the `Alternative` typeclass in terms of the coherence maps of the lax monoidal functor encoding:

```
(<|>) :: Alt f => f a -> f a -> f a
x <|> y = either id id <$> union (Left <$> x, Right <$> y)

empty :: Alternative f => f a
empty = absurd <$> nil ()
```

---

I define `Filterable` functors to be *oplax* monoidal functors from Hask under the `Either` tensor to Hask under the `(,)` tensor:

```
class Functor f => Filter f
  where
  partition :: f (a + b) -> f a × f b

class Filter f => Filterable f
  where
  trivial :: f Void -> ()
  trivial = const ()
```

Having for its laws just backwards lax monoidal functor laws:

Associativity:

```
bwd tassoc <<< bimap id partition <<< partition
=
bimap partition id <<< partition <<< fmap (bwd eassoc)
```

Left unit:

```
bwd tlunit
=
bimap trivial id <<< partition <<< fmap (bwd elunit)
```

Right unit:

```
bwd trunit
=
bimap id trivial <<< partition <<< fmap (bwd erunit)
```

Defining standard filter-y functions like `mapMaybe` and `filter` in terms of the oplax monoidal functor encoding left as an exercise to the interested reader:

```
mapMaybe :: Filterable f => (a -> Maybe b) -> f a -> f b
mapMaybe = _

filter :: Filterable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> f a
filter = _
```

---

The question is this: is every `Alternative` `Monad` also `Filterable`?

We can type tetris our way to an implementation:

```
instance (Alternative f, Monad f) => Filter f
  where
  partition fab = (fab >>= either return (const empty), fab >>= either (const empty) return)
```

But is this implementation always lawful? Is it sometimes lawful (for some formal definition of "sometimes")? Proofs, counterexamples, and/or informal arguments would all be very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I'd be pretty surprised if it were always valid. It's certainly *sometimes* valid in the sense that there exist functors for which it's valid, but I tend to doubt that's a particularly interesting class.

Comment: @dfeuer Do you have any counterexamples in mind for which it's obviously not valid? Perhaps that would be instructive.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is always a lawful instance, just from unfolding the definitions and some trivial rewriting (thus suggesting that the `Filterable` laws are quite weak). @AsadSaeeduddin Consider picking up some interactive theorem proving skills so you can extend the "use types, not your brain" mentality to proofs too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here goes an argument which is broadly supportive of your beautiful idea.

### Part one: mapMaybe

My plan here is restating the problem in terms of `mapMaybe`, hoping that doing so will bring us to more familiar ground. To do so, I will use a few `Either`-juggling utility functions:

```
maybeToRight :: a -> Maybe b -> Either a b
rightToMaybe :: Either a b -> Maybe b
leftToMaybe :: Either a b -> Maybe a
flipEither :: Either a b -> Either b a
```

(I took the first three names from [*relude*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/relude-0.6.0.0/docs/Relude-Monad-Either.html), and the fourth from [*errors*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.3.0/docs/Data-EitherR.html#v:flipEither). By the way, *errors* offers `maybeToRight` and `rightToMaybe` as `note` and `hush` respectively, in [`Control.Error.Util`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.3.0/docs/Control-Error-Util.html).)

As you noted, `mapMaybe` can be defined in terms of `partition`:

```
mapMaybe :: Filterable f => (a -> Maybe b) -> f a -> f b
mapMaybe f = snd . partition . fmap (maybeToRight () . f)
```

Crucially, we can also go the other way around:

```
partition :: Filterable f => f (Either a b) -> (f a, f b)
partition = mapMaybe leftToMaybe &&& mapMaybe rightToMaybe
```

This suggests it makes sense to recast your laws in terms of `mapMaybe`. With the identity laws, doing so gives us a great excuse to forget entirely about `trivial`:

```
-- Left and right unit
mapMaybe rightToMaybe . fmap (bwd elunit) = id  -- [I]
mapMaybe leftToMaybe . fmap (bwd erunit) = id   -- [II]
```

As for associativity, we can use `rightToMaybe` and `leftToMaybe` to split the law in three equations, one for each component we get from the successive partitions:

```
-- Associativity
mapMaybe rightToMaybe . fmap (bwd eassoc)
    = mapMaybe rightToMaybe . mapMaybe rightToMaybe  -- [III]
mapMaybe rightToMaybe . mapMaybe leftToMaybe . fmap (bwd eassoc)
    = mapMaybe leftToMaybe . mapMaybe rightToMaybe   -- [IV]
mapMaybe leftToMaybe . fmap (bwd eassoc)
    = mapMaybe leftToMaybe . mapMaybe leftToMaybe    -- [V]
```

Parametricity means `mapMaybe` is agnostic with respect to the `Either` values we are dealing with here. That being so, we can use our little arsenal of `Either` isomorphisms to shuffle things around and show that [I] is equivalent to [II], and [III] is equivalent to [V]. We are now down to three equations:

```
mapMaybe rightToMaybe . fmap (bwd elunit) = id       -- [I]
mapMaybe rightToMaybe . fmap (bwd eassoc)
    = mapMaybe rightToMaybe . mapMaybe rightToMaybe  -- [III]
mapMaybe rightToMaybe . mapMaybe leftToMaybe . fmap (bwd eassoc)
    = mapMaybe leftToMaybe . mapMaybe rightToMaybe   -- [IV]
```

Parametricity allows us to swallow the `fmap` in [I]:

```
mapMaybe (rightToMaybe . bwd elunit) = id
```

That, however, is simply...

```
mapMaybe Just = id
```

... which is equivalent to the conservation/identity law from [*witherable*'s `Filterable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable-class-0/docs/Data-Witherable-Class.html):

```
mapMaybe (Just . f) = fmap f
```

That `Filterable` also has a composition law:

```
-- The (<=<) is from the Maybe monad.
mapMaybe g . mapMaybe f = mapMaybe (g <=< f)
```

Can we also derive this one from our laws? Let's start from [III] and, once more, have parametricity do its work. This one is trickier, so I'll write it down in full:

```
mapMaybe rightToMaybe . fmap (bwd eassoc)
    = mapMaybe rightToMaybe . mapMaybe rightToMaybe  -- [III]

-- f :: a -> Maybe b; g :: b -> Maybe c
-- Precomposing fmap (right (maybeToRight () . g) . maybeToRight () . f)
-- on both sides:
mapMaybe rightToMaybe . fmap (bwd eassoc)
  . fmap (right (maybeToRight () . g) . maybeToRight () . f)
    = mapMaybe rightToMaybe . mapMaybe rightToMaybe 
      . fmap (right (maybeToRight () . g) . maybeToRight () . f)

mapMaybe rightToMaybe . mapMaybe rightToMaybe 
  . fmap (right (maybeToRight () . g) . maybeToRight () . f)  -- RHS
mapMaybe rightToMaybe . fmap (maybeToRight () . g)
  . mapMaybe rightToMaybe . fmap (maybeToRight () . f)
mapMaybe (rightToMaybe . maybeToRight () . g)
 . mapMaybe (rightToMaybe . maybeToRight () . f)
mapMaybe g . mapMaybe f

mapMaybe rightToMaybe . fmap (bwd eassoc)
  . fmap (right (maybeToRight () . g) . maybeToRight () . f)  -- LHS
mapMaybe (rightToMaybe . bwd eassoc 
    . right (maybeToRight () . g) . maybeToRight () . f)
mapMaybe (rightToMaybe . bwd eassoc 
    . right (maybeToRight ()) . maybeToRight () . fmap @Maybe g . f)
-- join @Maybe
--     = rightToMaybe . bwd eassoc . right (maybeToRight ()) . maybeToRight ()
mapMaybe (join @Maybe . fmap @Maybe g . f)
mapMaybe (g <=< f)  -- mapMaybe (g <=< f) = mapMaybe g . mapMaybe f
```

In the other direction:

```
mapMaybe (g <=< f) = mapMaybe g . mapMaybe f
-- f = rightToMaybe; g = rightToMaybe
mapMaybe (rightToMaybe <=< rightToMaybe)
    = mapMaybe rightToMaybe . mapMaybe rightToMaybe
mapMaybe (rightToMaybe <=< rightToMaybe)  -- LHS
mapMaybe (join @Maybe . fmap @Maybe rightToMaybe . rightToMaybe)
-- join @Maybe
--     = rightToMaybe . bwd eassoc . right (maybeToRight ()) . maybeToRight ()
mapMaybe (rightToMaybe . bwd eassoc 
    . right (maybeToRight ()) . maybeToRight ()
      . fmap @Maybe rightToMaybe . rightToMaybe)
mapMaybe (rightToMaybe . bwd eassoc 
    . right (maybeToRight () . rightToMaybe) 
      . maybeToRight () . rightToMaybe)
mapMaybe (rightToMaybe . bwd eassoc)  -- See note below.
mapMaybe rightToMaybe . fmap (bwd eassoc)
-- mapMaybe rightToMaybe . fmap (bwd eassoc)
--     = mapMaybe rightToMaybe . mapMaybe rightToMaybe
```

(Note: While `maybeToRight () . rightToMaybe :: Either a b -> Either () b` is not `id`, in the derivation above the left values will be discarded anyway, so it is fair to strike it out as if it were `id`.)

Thus [III] is equivalent to the composition law of *witherable*'s `Filterable`.

At this point, we can use the composition law to deal with [IV]:

```
mapMaybe rightToMaybe . mapMaybe leftToMaybe . fmap (bwd eassoc)
    = mapMaybe leftToMaybe . mapMaybe rightToMaybe   -- [IV]
mapMaybe (rightToMaybe <=< leftToMaybe) . fmap (bwd eassoc)
    = mapMaybe (letfToMaybe <=< rightToMaybe)
mapMaybe (rightToMaybe <=< leftToMaybe . bwd eassoc)
    = mapMaybe (letfToMaybe <=< rightToMaybe)
-- Sufficient condition:
rightToMaybe <=< leftToMaybe . bwd eassoc = letfToMaybe <=< rightToMaybe
-- The condition holds, as can be directly verified by substiuting the definitions.
```

This suffices to show your class amounts to a well-established formulation of `Filterable`, which is a very nice result. Here is a recap of the laws:

```
mapMaybe Just = id                            -- Identity
mapMaybe g . mapMaybe f = mapMaybe (g <=< f)  -- Composition
```

As the *witherable* docs note, these are functor laws for a functor from **Kleisli Maybe** to **Hask**.

### Part two: Alternative and Monad

Now we can tackle your actual question, which was about alternative monads. Your proposed implementation of `partition` was:

```
partitionAM :: (Alternative f, Monad f) => f (Either a b) -> (f a, f b)
partitionAM
    = (either return (const empty) =<<) &&& (either (const empty) return =<<)
```

Following my broader plan, I will switch to the `mapMaybe` presentation:

```
mapMaybe f
snd . partition . fmap (maybeToRight () . f)
snd . (either return (const empty) =<<) &&& (either (const empty) return =<<)
    . fmap (maybeToRight () . f)
(either (const empty) return =<<) . fmap (maybeToRight () . f)
(either (const empty) return . maybeToRight . f =<<)
(maybe empty return . f =<<)
```

And so we can define:

```
mapMaybeAM :: (Alternative f, Monad f) => (a -> Maybe b) -> f a -> f b
mapMaybeAM f u = maybe empty return . f =<< u
```

Or, in a pointfree spelling:

```
mapMaybeAM = (=<<) . (maybe empty return .)
```

A few paragraphs above, I noted the `Filterable` laws say that `mapMaybe` is the morphism mapping of a functor from **Kleisli Maybe** to **Hask**. Since the composition of functors is a functor, and `(=<<)` is the morphism mapping of a functor from **Kleisli f** to **Hask**, `(maybe empty return .)` being the morphism mapping of a functor from **Kleisli Maybe** to **Kleisli f** suffices for `mapMaybeAM` to be lawful. The relevant functor laws are:

```
maybe empty return . Just = return  -- Identity
maybe empty return . g <=< maybe empty return . f
    = maybe empty return . (g <=< f)  -- Composition
```

This identity law holds, so let's focus on the composition one:

```
maybe empty return . g <=< maybe empty return . f
    = maybe empty return . (g <=< f)
maybe empty return . g =<< maybe empty return (f a)
    = maybe empty return (g =<< f a)
-- Case 1: f a = Nothing
maybe empty return . g =<< maybe empty return Nothing
    = maybe empty return (g =<< Nothing)
maybe empty return . g =<< empty = maybe empty return Nothing
maybe empty return . g =<< empty = empty  -- To be continued.
-- Case 2: f a = Just b
maybe empty return . g =<< maybe empty return (Just b)
    = maybe empty return (g =<< Just b)
maybe empty return . g =<< return b = maybe empty return (g b)
maybe empty return (g b) = maybe empty return (g b)  -- OK.
```

Therefore, `mapMaybeAM` is lawful iff `maybe empty return . g =<< empty = empty` for any `g`. Now, if `empty` is defined as `absurd <$> nil ()`, as you have done here, we can prove that `f =<< empty = empty` for any `f`:

```
f =<< empty = empty
f =<< empty  -- LHS
f =<< absurd <$> nil ()
f . absurd =<< nil ()
-- By parametricity, f . absurd = absurd, for any f.
absurd =<< nil ()
return . absurd =<< nil ()
absurd <$> nil ()
empty  -- LHS = RHS
```

Intuitively, if `empty` is really empty (as it must be, given the definition we are using here), there will be no values for `f` to be applied to, and so `f =<< empty` can't result in anything but `empty`.

A different approach here would be looking into the interaction of the `Alternative` and `Monad` classes. As it happens, there is a class for alternative monads: [`MonadPlus`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.8.3/docs/html/libraries/base-4.13.0.0/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus). Accordingly, a restyled `mapMaybe` might look like this:

```
-- Lawful iff, for any f, mzero >>= maybe empty mzero . f = mzero
mmapMaybe :: MonadPlus m => (a -> Maybe b) -> m a -> m b
mmapMaybe f m = m >>= maybe mzero return . f
```

While there are [varying opinions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Alternative_and_MonadPlus#Other_suggested_laws) on which set of laws is most appropriate for `MonadPlus`, one of the laws no one seems to object to is...

```
mzero >>= f = mzero  -- Left zero
```

... which is precisely the property of `empty` we were discussing a few paragraphs above. The lawfulness of `mmapMaybe` follows immediately from the left zero law.

(Incidentally, [`Control.Monad` provides `mfilter :: MonadPlus m => (a -> Bool) -> m a -> m a`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.8.3/docs/html/libraries/base-4.13.0.0/Control-Monad.html#v:mfilter), which matches the `filter` we can define using `mmapMaybe`.)

In summary:

> But is this implementation always lawful? Is it sometimes lawful (for some formal definition of "sometimes")?

Yes, the implementation is lawful. This conclusion hinges on the `empty` being indeed empty, as it should, or on the relevant alternative monad following the left zero `MonadPlus` law, which boils down to pretty much the same thing.

It is worth emphasising that `Filterable` isn't subsumed by `MonadPlus`, as we can illustrate with the following counterexamples:

- `ZipList`: filterable, but not a monad. The `Filterable` instance is the same as the one for lists, even though the `Alternative` one is different.
- `Map`: filterable, but neither a monad nor applicative. In fact, `Map` can't even be applicative because there is no sensible implementation of `pure`. It does, however, have its own `empty`.
- `MaybeT f`: while its `Monad` and `Alternative` instances require `f` to be a monad, and an isolated `empty` definition would need at least `Applicative`, the `Filterable` instance only requires `Functor f` (anything becomes filterable if you slip a `Maybe` layer into it).

### Part three: empty

At this point, one might still wonder how big of a role `empty`, or `nil`, really plays in `Filterable`. It is not a class method, and yet most instances appear to have a sensible version of it lying around.

The one thing we can be certain of is that, if the filterable type has any inhabitants at all, at least one of them will be an empty structure, because we can always take any inhabitant and filter everything out:

```
chop :: Filterable f => f a -> f Void
chop = mapMaybe (const Nothing)
```

The existence of `chop`, though doesn't mean there will be a *single* `nil` empty value, or that `chop` will always give out the same result. Consider, for instance, `MaybeT IO`, whose `Filterable` instance might be thought of as a way to censor results of `IO` computations. The instance is perfectly lawful, even though `chop` can produce distinct `MaybeT IO Void` values that carry arbitrary `IO` effects.

On a final note, you have [alluded to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60732274/is-every-alternative-monad-filterable/60796049#comment107679715_60796049) the possibility of working with strong monoidal functors, so that `Alternative` and `Filterable` are linked by making `union`/`partition` and `nil`/`trivial` isomorphisms. Having `union` and `partition` as mutual inverses is conceivable but fairly limiting, given that `union . partition` discards some information about the arrangement of the elements for a large share of instances. As for the other isomorphism, `trivial . nil` is trivial, but `nil . trivial` is interesting in that it implies there is just a single `f Void` value, something that holds for a sizeable share of `Filterable` instances. It happens that there is a `MonadPlus` version of this condition. If we demand that, for any `u`...

```
absurd <$> chop u = mzero
```

... and then substitute the `mmapMaybe` from part two, we get:

```
absurd <$> chop u = mzero
absurd <$> mmapMaybe (const Nothing) u = mzero
mmapMaybe (fmap absurd . const Nothing) u = mzero
mmapMaybe (const Nothing) u = mzero
u >>= maybe mzero return . const Nothing = mzero
u >>= const mzero = mzero
u >> mzero = mzero
```

This property is known as the right zero law of `MonadPlus`, though [there are good reasons to contest its status as a law](https://winterkoninkje.dreamwidth.org/90905.html) of that particular class.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up! I haven't had time to go through all of this yet, but is fair to say that the summary is: "not without additional laws relating the `Monad` and `Alternative` instances"?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Yup. `MonadPlus` (possibly seen through [the near-semiring characterisation](https://www.fceia.unr.edu.ar/~mauro/pubs/FromMonoidstoNearsemirings.pdf)) sets up a connection between `Alternative` and `Monad` that the unadorned "monoidal functor from Hask-with-`(,)` to Hask-with-`Either`" characterisation doesn't offer. In any case, I'm still wondering if there is something deeper about how `empty`, which looks foreign to the bare `Filterable` definition and yet feels quite fitting, shows up here.

Comment: `empty` is part of the definition of `Alternative`. The `Alternative` and `Filterable` can be more closely related by demanding that `union` is the inverse of `partition` (and vice versa), and that `trivial` is the inverse of `nil` (and vice versa). This is what's called a "strong monoidal functor".

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin For some of the common `Filterable` instances, that property would be too strong, as `partition` can be lossy. For instance, `(union . partition) [L 7, R 2, L 1, R 6]` is `[L 7, L 1, R 2, R 6]`. The `trivial`/`nil` part would ultimately boil down to having just one `f Void` value, which seems more amenable. In `MonadPlus` terms, it corresponds to the contested right zero law, `m >> mzero = mzero`, which, for instance, holds for lists but not for parsers.

Comment: Not every filterable has that property, yes, just as not every lax monoidal functor is strong monoidal. That's why it makes sense to have both concepts.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Something that I had overlooked the first time around: if `empty = absurd <$> nil ()`, then we can prove `f =<< empty = empty` for any `f`, which means we don't necessarily have to rely on the `MonadPlus` left zero law here.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I have appended a section distilling my thoughts on `empty`. This is possibly the final update :)

Comment: Thanks for your patience and all the insights. I've started trying to follow your reasoning by copying it to Agda, I'll accept the answer as soon as that's done.

Comment: thank you again, and sorry about the incredibly long delay in accepting your thorough and enlightening answer.